# CSS align 2 block bottom

Tags: css, alignment

I have 2 block, `red` block `width: fixed height: auto`, `green` block `width` and `height fixed`, I don't know how to align `green` block that it will be on bottom, now it's on top;
Can see example: http://jsfiddle.net/MXqTY/3/

Comment: you want the divs to be one on top of the other, or side by side, but aligned at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```css
.square1, .square2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

and remove `float: left`.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/MXqTY/8/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float:left from your class declaration.  By default they will stack.  Floating both elements to the left will cause them to stack horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

adding `clear:left;` to your `.square2` block will solve your problem.

```css
#wrap{
margin: 0 auto;
}

.square1{
width: 100px;
height: auto;
background-color: red;
float: left;
}
.square2{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: green;
float: left;
clear:left;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id='wrap'>

    <div class='square1'>tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas tekstas  </div>
    <div class='square2'></div>

</div>
```

The reason why your green block is aligning alongside your other floated block is because float automatically shifts all elements to the indicated position within a containing element. You can see that definition [here on MDN.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW0gx.png)

All floated elements will line up next to each other until it reaches the end of the container at which point it wraps around to the next line. By adding `clear` to your block of code for `.square2` you are essentially telling it to move to the edge of all relevant floats which in your case is the first square.

Answer (score -3):

For `.square2`, add:

```
margin-top:110px;
```

Comment: and what when I add more text to square1 ?

Comment: Using a top margin will not work if the height of `square1` changes.

Comment: Correct, but THIS WAS NEVER PART OF THE QUESTION.